# Sencha blank app not working in ios 5 safari

Tags: javascript, extjs, ios5, safari

I have generated blank Extjs 5 application with sencha cmd 5 (main view, etc.) and tried hosting it view sencha app watch and IIS. It opens normally on desktop browsers but when I try in Safari or Chrome of iPhone 4 with ios5, page is blank without errors.

I also noticed that Extjs 5 examples are all blank on same iPhone.

Does anyone have similar problems? I mostly still work with Extjs 3, which opens fine on same device.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The [Ext JS 5 Kitchen Sink example](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/) works fine for me on my iPhone 4 (in Mobile Safari anyhow), though it's clearly not designed for viewing on a phone (Ext JS 5 is designed to support tablets and desktops only).

Having said this, Ext JS 5 is currently a beta release... so without physically seeing your app I can't explain why it wouldn't load.

Since you're running it on IIS, I should point out that IIS usually requires that you enable the ".json " file extension manually - and because Ext JS 5 (in apps build with Cmd) uses some bootstrapped JSON files, IIS might not honor those network requests until you enable that MIME type.

Comment: I did add json mime to iis, that is not an issue. You probably have ios > 5 on Iphone 4? I tested it on ios 7 and it works. Im confused about the roadmap for extjs5.. I thought they will try to merge sencha touch and extjs into single framework and developer will be able to add separate views for mobile/tablet/desktop but still write main models/controllers only once...